# Azure Data Factory, utcNow() dynamic function used to create new folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Copy Data activity to send data to Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2. To do so, I must create a new folder every day that has the current timestamp at the end of it. So today my pipeline launches, in the proper path in the Storage Explorer I should see:

Folder_name_2021-11-02

I don't care about the format, I just need the date. In 'path' ('Sink' section of Copy data activity) I wrote:

@parent_folder/folder_name_utcNow()

But I get the following error:
@parent_folder/folder_name_utcNow() is not valid: the string character '/' at position '13' is not expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the string in the right format and put it in the right place.  Here is an example where I am using `concat` to join multiple strings with `formatDateTime` to convert the output of `utcNow` into a string format I can use in a filename. I am using this dynamic content in the **File path** property of the Sink output dataset.

NB I am using the forward slashes in my format string ensure I get that data lake hierarchy.  If you just want a single file with the date in it, replace them with underscores or remove them altogether:

```
@concat('raw/ball/', formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy/MM/dd/HH/mm/'))
```

The output dataset:

[image]

You probably want something like:

```
@concat('raw/parent_folder/folder_name_/', formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyyMMdd'))
```

Although it is more common to use the date folders as per my original example.